# Deducing variadic template depending on argument count

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

Imagine I have two functions:

```
void string(const char *str)
{
    std::cout << "this is string" << std::endl;
}

void number(const char *str, double f)
{
    std::cout << "this is number" << std::endl;
}
```

I want to write a generic wrapper so that be able to call `format()` like this:

```
int main() {
    format("single arg");
    format("format string", 1.0);
    format("single arg", "format string", 1.0);
    format("format string 1", 1.0, "just string arg", "format string 2", 2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

That is if arguments come in pair {string, number}, then invoke `number()`; otherwise call `string()`. Obviously, it can be done only unpacking arguments right-to-left. I've tried to implement it following (wrong) way:

```
template<class T>
void operation(T first)
{
    string(first);
}

template<class T, class U = float>
void operation(T first, U second)
{
    number(first, second);
}

template<class ... ARGS>
void format(ARGS ... args)
{
    auto last = (args, ...);
    using last_type = typename decltype(last);
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<last_type>)
        (..., operation(args, last));
    else
        (..., operation(args)); 
}
```

The problem is that while unpacking `operation(args, last)` we will get both `args` and `last` floats. I believe there's some easy way to achieve what I want (without relying on tuples etc).

Comment: Are you trying achieve something like: [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or [fmt::format](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html)? It is unclear what is the general goal of this code. Consider providing examples of usage of this templates with expected result (output).

Comment: It seems like you're overthinking this. Two overloaded `format()` functions. One with one parameter. One with two parameters. The End.

Comment: @MarekR I'm trying to achieve exactly what I put in the example. Just in educational purposes. Examples of `format` interface are inlined in the post.

@SamVarshavchik I'm not. Please refer to the original question.

Comment: you may change it to use fluent interface instead of parameter pack. which is way easier to understand imo.

Comment: @NikitaRock no, "what you put in the example" is not clear. show input and output and why.

Comment: @NikitaRock your description is not clear enough, so please [edit] your question to improve it. I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one confused what is actual aim. Communicating your intent is important skill when asking question or writing code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proof-of-concept using only overload resolution. I'm not sure how scalable it is, though.

```
void format() {}

void format(char const *str) {
    string(str);
}

template <class... Args>
void format(char const *str, char const *nextStr, Args... args);

template <class... Args>
void format(char const *str, double f, Args... args);

template <class... Args>
void format(char const *str, char const *nextStr, Args... args) {
    string(str);
    format(nextStr, args...);
}

template <class... Args>
void format(char const *str, double f, Args... args) {
    number(str, f);
    format(args...);
}
```

[See it live on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/e7nGdW1e8)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks exactly what I want (all examples seem to compile). I would just change explicit `char const *` and `float` to template types like: https://godbolt.org/z/q1KhPzGYx

Comment: @NikitaRock, then look at where the error for `format(1.0, 1.0, "format string", 1.0);` occurs in the two cases. I think the proposed solution can be improved with concepts, but with a plain template it's probably pejorative.

Comment: @Enlico error is fine in this case, that's what I want:) The interface is not suitable for your example, so error underlines it.

Comment: What??? I'm just saying that in the two cases the error occurs at different places. [Quentin code errors at the overload resolution for `format`](https://godbolt.org/z/nY87G8jYE), whereas [yours errors first inside its implementation, when trying to use `string`](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: Anyway, I still have one question. Suggested by @quentin solution looks like "LR1" parser - means that we use single look ahead symbols to deduce proper function. In my original attempt to solve this problem I tried to smth like "RL0" - deducing arguments from right to left. And in this case only current argument is enough (since in case we meet float/string - we know for sure our path). Is it possible to achieve in easy way?

Comment: @Enlico It is ok, I understand, it doesn't seem to be a problem (in my particular case).